# C++ custom dll and 3rd party libraries

Tags: c++, dll

I am trying to 
build a dll library which uses third party libraries (i have an option to use static or dynamic linking with those 3rd party libs). When my main project builds it always looks for those 3rd party dependencies (i do not use any of the calls from 3rd party libs in my main program). I managed to build main program but it requires 3rd party dependencies. Is there some way to shield my main program from those 3rd party dependencies and to include them directly in dll i`m building so my main program is not aware of what dll or libs are used in dll implementation?

main program <- my dll (i`m building) <- 3rd party lib or dll

<- uses

Comment: Do you use MSVC++?

Comment: It is certainly possible to compile main program if you have DLL and its import library (LIB). If you use MSVC++, it is probably project dependency issue: main program project depends on DLL project, DLL project depends on 3rd-party library.

Comment: Try this. Create two separate solutions: main program and your library. Build your library. Use header, import library (LIB) and DLL in main solution as files. Then try to build main program.

Comment: Thanks fort the help i did it. It requires managing the inclusion macros from dll. 
Since .h file from .dll includes .h file from .lib file and main program includes .h from .dll, it must have access to .h from the .lib. 
Little macro managing solved the problem.